# Using CASE in SQL Server - getting "because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, aggregate-functions

I want to show the days since the last customer order from a certain storenumber, I have been told to use `CASE`.

I don't want to use `MAX` or `MIN` because it may ignore other records for said customer.

```
 SELECT ms.CustomerID AS email,
  AS last_txn_days_online, 
   CASE
       WHEN ST2.StoreNumber != '100799' THEN CEILING(Round(DateDiff(DAY, Min(st2.PurchaseDate), Max(st2.PurchaseDate)) / NULLIF(Count(st2.CustomerID) - 1, 0),0))
       ELSE NULL
   END AS last_txn_days_instore
 FROM [Not MS] ms
 LEFT JOIN [ORDER_HEADER] st2 ON ms.CustomerID = st2.CustomerID
 GROUP BY MS.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation.  The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT ms.CustomerID AS email,
       CEILING(Round(DateDiff(DAY,
                              Min(CASE WHEN ST2.StoreNumber <> '100799' THEN st2.PurchaseDate END), 
M                             MAX(CASE WHEN ST2.StoreNumber <> '100799' THEN st2.PurchaseDate END)
                             )  / NULLIF(Count(CASE WHEN ST2.StoreNumber <> '100799' THEN st2.CustomerID END) - 1, 0), 0
                    ) 
              )
   END AS last_txn_days_instore
FROM [Not MS] ms LEFT JOIN
     [ORDER_HEADER] st2
     ON ms.CustomerID = st2.CustomerID
 GROUP BY MS.CustomerID
```